# RenderTargetBitmap hardware accelerated analog

Tags: performance, rendertargetbitmap

Is there a RenderTargetBitmap hardware accelerated analog in .net 3.5 sp1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is answered at MSDN forums that [there is no hardware accelerated alternative in 3.5 SP1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7a6b1eb9-69ed-49e3-a0aa-f9616f4a549e/rendertargetbitmap-hardware-accelerated-analog?forum=wpf).